# При замене класса не меняется фон кнопки

Tags: javascript, css

скрипт меняет класс и, соответственно, фон кнопки. Но не меняет. Помогите!`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){       
    $("#old").change(function(){
        $(".but").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
</script>`
<style>
.active{
    background: #000000;
}
.but{
    background: #00BFCD;
    border: none;
}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="old" >go
<button class="but">скачать</button>
```

Comment: Сначало html, затем script. Или вместо создания и вызовы функции `$(function(){ ... });` выполнять скрипт по загрузке DOM элементов `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: @Doofy, `$(function(){ ... })` это краткая форма записи `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Comment: Советую сначало изучить основы javascript, потом браться за фреймоврки типа jquery. `$(function() { ... })` это обёртка функций jquery не обязательна. Внутри уже назначен обработчик события `.change()`

Comment: не работает! Если задать color - меняется только color, а background ни в какую. И неважно, где расположен script - в начале документа или в конце.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, можно и без JS обойтись:

```css
.but {
  background: #00BFCD;
  border: none;
}
#old:checked +.but {
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="old">go
<button class="but">скачать</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в каскадности стилей, класс *active* описан раньше и задает то же свойство, что и класс *but*, поэтому применяется значение из класса *but*.

Для решения нужно просто поменять местами определение классов

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#old").change(function() {
      $(".but").toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
<style>
  .but {
    background: #00BFCD;
    border: none;
  }
  .active {
    background: #000000;
  }
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="old">go
<button class="but">скачать</button>
```

Comment: круто. Я потратил 2 часа. Спасибо за умный и быстрый ответ.